# Getting time between two times with time span of one hour

Tags: c#, datetime, timespan

I have two times like

```
Time A:09:00 AM
```

and `Time B:06:00 PM`
I want to get the total hours between Time A and Time B
and show it with the time span of 1 hour
e.g:

```
09:00 AM

10:00 AM

11:00 AM

12:00 PM

upto

06:00 PM
```

Comment: Could you show us the part of your code where you're getting stuck?

Comment: still unable to create a logic for that
only have code to get total hours

`string B= "09:00 AM";
string B= "06:00 PM";

TimeSpan duration = DateTime.Parse(endTime).Subtract(DateTime.Parse(startTime));`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need something like;

```
DateTime dt1 = DateTime.Parse("09:00 AM");
DateTime dt2 = DateTime.Parse("06:00 PM");
while (dt1 <= dt2)
{
     Console.WriteLine(dt1.ToString("hh:mm tt"));
     dt1 = dt1.AddHours(1);
}
```

Output will be;

```
09:00 AM
10:00 AM
11:00 AM
12:00 PM
01:00 PM
02:00 PM
03:00 PM
04:00 PM
05:00 PM
06:00 PM
```

Here's a [demonstration](http://ideone.com/8qbNr0).

I'm sorry but I don't understand why you interested in `TimeSpan` on this case. It is a duration in time. You need to get every hour times with `DateTime`.

Answer (score 3):

Use this function:

```
public static IEnumerable<DateTime> GetHours(DateTime startTime, DateTime endTime)
{
    var currentTime = startTime;

    while (currentTime <= endTime)
    {
        yield return currentTime;
        currentTime = currentTime.AddHours(1);
    }
}
```

If you just need the number of hours between two events, you can use a variation of

```
(endTime - startTime).TotalHours
```

This will return a `double`. To calculate the number of items returned from the iterator, use

```
(int)(endTime - startTime).TotalHours + 1
```